# Iterating through external nested Json to make accordian menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My problem sounds simple in theory but I have been having a lot of trouble getting the menu to work properly.

What is going on is that I can get the menu to get the title of the menu item like I want, but I cannot properly retrieve the inside items nor get them to display right.

Here is my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  $.getJSON( "externalJson.json", function( data ) {
     postData(data);
});

var html = '<ul>';

function postData(data){
   /* 
   How I want my menu to work in structure:

    <ul>
        <li>
            <h3><span>Header</span></h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>

    </ul>
    */
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        console.log(data[key].innerItem);

        html += "<li><h3><span>" + key + "</span></h3>";

        $.each(data[key].innerItem, function(i, j){
            console.log(j.item);

            html += "<ul>";
            html += "<li><a href=" + j.link + ">" + j.item + "</a></li>";
            html += "</ul>";

        });

        html += "</li>";
        html += "</ul>";

    });

    $('#accordian').append(html);

};


$("#accordian h3").click(function(){

    $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();

    if(!$(this).next().is(":visible")){
        $(this).next().slideDown();

    }
});

});
```

and here is my JSON file, which is in a separate file:

```
   {

  "ItemOne":
    {
     "innerItem":
            [{
                "item":"cat",
                "link":"http://www.google.com/"
            }]
    },

"ItemTwo":
    {
      "innerItem":
            [{
                "item":"kitten",
                "link":"http://www.google.com/"
            }]
    },

"ItemThree":
    {
     "innerItem":
            [{
                "item":"meow",
                "link":"http://www.google.com/"
            }]
    },

"ItemFour":
    {
       "innerItem":
            [{
                "item":"purr",
                "link":"http://www.google.com/"
            }]
    }
  }
```

If you wish to look at all of my code, here's a link: https://ide.c9.io/cherrysymphony/workspace#openfile-README.md

I don't quite understand what I need to do to make the code work properly like when I hardcode it into the html.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but could this be the solution?

```js
$.each(data, function(key, value){
  console.log(data[key].innerItem);

  html += "<li><h3><span>" + key + "</span></h3>";

  html += "<ul>";
  $.each(data[key].innerItem, function(i, j){
    console.log(j.item);

    html += "<li><a href=" + j.link + ">" + j.item + "</a></li>";

  });
  html += "</ul>";

  html += "</li>";
  html += "</ul>";

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. Basically, what I need is to be able to loop through the items to get to their nested subitems and access the values stored in those.

Comment: Maybe include the desired HTML result form the JSON you included in the question...

Comment: If you can view the link in the question, then you should be able to see the desired outcome in the menu item labeled "Desired".

Comment: you should have access now